# Override individual Vuetify icon with Font Awesome SVG icon

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuetify.js, font-awesome

Is it possible to override **individual** icons from Vuetify with Font Awesome svg icons, without writing an custom component for each icon?

Something like this: ???

```
import { svgPathData as envelopeSvg } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faEnvelope'
import { svgPathData as questionCircleSvg } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faQuestionCircle'


Vue.use(Vuetify)

const app = new Vue({
vuetify: new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'md',
        values: {
            email: envelopeSvg,
            question_circle: questionCircleSvg
        }
    },
...
})
```

**Update**
I kind of got the above code working, but now my current issue is the v-icon component renders using the wrong viewbox size.

```
<font-awesome-icon class="icon" icon="envelope" /> //viewBox="0 0 512 512"
<v-icon class="icon">email</v-icon> //viewBox="0 0 24 24"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add proper way

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#font-awesome-5-icons

`yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free -D`

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'fa',
  },
})
```

UPDATE:
according to [Git Issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11224)

You need to install all fonts you need or add links to CDNs, iconfont only specifies which icon set will be used for default Vueitfy icons (such as arrow in v-select etc)

```
<v-icon>mdi-user</v-icon> // MDI will be used
<v-icon>user<v-icon> // Material Icons will be used
<v-icon>fas fa-whatever<v-icon> // FA will be used
```

Comment: I believe this switches Vuetify to use all FA webfonts, which is not what I want.  I want to continue using the built in Material Design icons and override specific icons with Font Awesome svg icons.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Did my update answer you question?

Comment: I ended up going a different route, but I think what you are saying would work. - Thanks